# how to call onchange remoteFunction in gsp with multiple parameters?

Tags: grails, onchange, gsp

The goal is to update a property of "staff" while choosing a new manager for a specific department. The property that needs to be updated belongs to the previous head of department, hence the need for the record id of the previous manager.

If you look at the code below, "this.value" will deliver me correctly the record id of the newly chosen manager (dropdown combo in a GSP) but I cannot seem to pass the record id of the previous manager with a simple ${deptInstance?.manager?.id} to the ajax remoteFunction

the relationship between them: staff ---1:N---> dept

code snippet in GSP:

```
<g:select
    name="manager.id" 
    from="${Staff.list()}" 
    optionKey="id" 
    value="${deptInstance?.manager?.id}" 
    onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'managerMaintenance', params:'\'oldmanager=\' + this.value + \'&newmanager=\' + this.value')};">
```

So far so good, I get the two parameters.

Only problem is that once I use ${groupInstance?.manager?.id} instead of "this.value" for the oldmanager parameter, then I cannot receive anything in the controller method "managerMaintenance"

Does anyone have an idea how to reference the previous value of a dropdown combo in a gsp  remoteFunction call?

Maybe my approach is wrong but I would appreciate any inputs concerning the right GSP syntax or a possible workaround to this.

Many thanks in advance,
sphere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question if you even need to pass `oldmanager` at all as a param.

A cleaner approach would be to read to obtain the previous value for manager within your `managerMaintenance` controller action.

Example gsp:

```
<g:select
...
onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'managerMaintenance', id:deptInstance?.id, params:[manager.id:this.value])}">
```

Example Controller:

```
def managerMaintenance = {
   def deptInstance = Department.get(params.id)

   def oldManager = defInstance.manager

   deptInstance.properties = params

   def newManager = defInstance.manager
}
```

Of course, there is this nice trick if you need it too...

```
domainInstance.getPersistentValue('propertyName')
```